The instance of entity type "Question" cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked
When trying to patch the mission object I got this error you see in the title.
Mission mission = await context.Missions.Include(m => m.Position)
                    .Include(m => m.Questions).ThenInclude(q => q.Answers)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.MissionId == missionViewModel.MissionId);

                if (mission != null)
                {
                    mapper.Map(missionViewModel, mission);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();//gives error
                    return Created($"/api/missions/{mission.MissionId}",
                        mapper.Map<Mission, MissionViewModel>(mission));
                }


public class Mission
{
    [Key]
    public int MissionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

I did manage to fix it after searching for many hours on the internet, the answer is a combination of some answers for the same error caused by something else. Since I couldn't find an exact answer for my issue, I made one myself here in case someone has this same exact issue in the future.
The issue happens when there is a collection of an entitie being tracked, in this case the questions property in the mission entity caused it.

In case you're getting this error when you call SaveChanges() like I did then here is a solution that worked for my case:
Mission mission = await context.Missions.Include(m => m.Position).AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(m => m.Questions).ThenInclude(q => q.Answers)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.MissionId == missionViewModel.MissionId);

                if (mission != null)
                {
                    mapper.Map(missionViewModel, mission);
                    context.Update(mission);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return Created($"/api/missions/{mission.MissionId}",
                        mapper.Map<Mission, MissionViewModel>(mission));
                }

First, notice the ".AsNoTracking()" on the first line, this stops tracking the object changes, then after I have done my changes by mapping from my viewmodel to the object itself, I use the Update() to track the object changes before the SaveChanges(), this way the SaveChanges() won't throw the exception and it will write out the changes.

It looks like you've redacted some code from your question, because what you've posted should not generate an error. As such, this answer is not necessary either. There's likely something going on between when you're selecting the mission and when you're saving it back, and that is where the problem lies. What you've done here is just masking that problem.

@ChrisPratt yes the code that is in the aswer works, the code in the question doesn't work because the questions property is a Collection of question entity, and for some reason it gives that error, if there is no such propery in the entity you're updating then the code in the question works fine. I'll add the mission entity to the question to make it more understandable.

That's because you're mapping over a collection, which confuses EF's change tracking. It essentially looks like you're attempting to add a new item when actually you're want to update an existing one. Since the id already exists, EF gives you that error. There's a NuGet that can help you out with mapping collections: AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore.
